# How can I type a function argument as native function

Tags: python-3.6, type-hinting, mypy, type-annotation

I have a helper function to use in python repl to move variables to global for easy debugging. But there is a mypy error:

```
class stepin(object):  # pylint: disable=R0903
    def __init__(self, func: Callable) -> None:
        self.func = func
        self.args = func.__code__.co_varnames
        if hasattr(func, "__defaults__") and func.__defaults__:
            self.defaults = dict(zip(reversed(self.args), reversed(func.__defaults__)))
        else:
            self.defaults = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result_dict = {x: None for x in self.args}
        if self.defaults:
            result_dict.update(self.defaults)
        result_dict.update(dict(zip(self.args, args)))
        result_dict.update(kwargs)
        for x in result_dict.keys():
            if result_dict[x] is None:
                raise ValueError('Missing args: ', self.func.__qualname__, x)
        globals().update(result_dict)
```

Now, the line

```
if hasattr(func, "__defaults__") and func.__defaults__:
    self.defaults = dict(zip(reversed(self.args), reversed(func.__defaults__)))
```

raises a mypy error that says func has no __defaults__
Now I understand that the BDFL has said he despises the "hasattr" check so it's probably not gonna be solved inside mypy; then my question is, is there a way to change the __init__ typing signature to get rid of the error?

What have I tried: Callable doesn't work, understandable: not all Callables have __defaults__.
But where is the type "function"? If I type() a function it says "function" but "function" is not in preamble or "typing". I see that some people mention "FunctionType" but it's not in "typing" either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a function is `types.FunctionType` (in the `types` module).

If you modify the annotation for `func` from `Callable` to `types.FunctionType`, mypy no longer complains about `__defaults__`.